Getting exception while setting up an detox project
Getting exception after executing this command
npx detox build -c android
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac'.


Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

BUILD FAILED in 3s
95 actionable tasks: 17 executed, 78 up-to-date
react native
detoxrc.js file :
/** @type {Detox.DetoxConfig} */
module.exports = {
  testRunner: {
    args: {
      '$0': 'jest',
      config: 'e2e/jest.config.js'
    },
    jest: {
      setupTimeout: 120000
    }
  },
  apps: {
    'android.debug': {
      type: 'android.apk',
      binaryPath: 'android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk',
      build: 'cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug',
      reversePorts: [8081]
    }
  },

  devices: {
    emulator: {
      type: 'android.emulator',
      device: {
        avdName: 'Pixel_API_33_AOSP'
      }
    }
  },
  configurations: {
    'android.emu.debug': {
      device: 'emulator',
      app: 'android.debug'
    },
'android.debug': {
      device: 'emulator',
      app: 'android.debug'
    }
  }

};

